# Plotting frequency distribution through time (stacked)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot how many people there were in a shop by date. 
To do this, first I grouped by date people's names:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Name']).size()
```

The result is shown below

```
    Date        Name  


2020-01-25  John       1
2020-01-26  John       1
2020-01-27  John       1
2020-01-28  Luca       1
            John       1
                 ..
2020-03-30  John       1
2020-03-31  Martyn     2
            Christine  1
            Mary       1
            John       1
```

Now, I would like to see how many people there were each day (`1` on `25/01`, `1` on `26/01`, `1` on `27/01`, `3` on `28/01`, and so on), and who. 
So I would need a histogram (bar plot) that can help me to visualise these results. In order to see the frequency of same people on the same day (like Martyn, that went twice), I would need to consider a stacked plot (I think). 
Since the number of names is around 1000, could you please tell me if it would be possible to have a legend/labels that can be readable?

Could you please show me how to do this? Plots are my weakness (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use a combination of [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html) and maplotlib. Seaborn has very simple, out-of-the-box graphs for you to use, then you can customise them with matplotlib.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create blank figure instance using matplotlib syntax, for easier customisation
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))

#manipulate your data
dfg = df.groupby(['Date', 'Name']).size().reset_index()

#call the 'barplot' from seaborn, which is what you're after. You could even use 
#'countplot' and skip the groupby step in your data.
sns.barplot(data=dfg,x='Date',y='Size',ax=ax1)

#customise your plot with matplotlib
ax1.set_title('Customers attending shops')
```

Comment: Hi @KWx. I got this warning: `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:1713: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use arr[tuple(seq)] instead of arr[seq]. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, arr[np.array(seq)], which will result either in an error or a different result.
  return np.add.reduce(sorted[indexer] * weights, axis=axis) / sumval`

Comment: I'm unsure sorry. When you do a groupby it creates a multiindex, which is a sequence of tuples. It probably refers to that. Did the graph work?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks KWx